Add Messages to Service Bus Queue and Return a standard response Http
I am using .NET Isolated Functions
I need to send multiple messages to a queue
So I am using the code below
[Function("process-duplicates")]
public async Task<DispatchedMessages> ProcessDataAsync([Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous,
        "post", Route = "myroute")]
    HttpRequest req,
    IAsyncCollector<string> asyncCollector)
{
    await _passfortDataService.ProcessDataAsync();

    return new DispatchedMessages
    {
        Messages = myService.MessagesToBeSent.Select(x => x.ToJson()),
        Status = new OkObjectResult("Processed Data")
    };
}

Where DispatchedMessages is
public class DispatchedMessages
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    [ServiceBusOutput("QueueName", Connection = "event-bus-connection")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Messages { get; set; }

    public IActionResult Status { get; set; }

}

When I run this it works fine in terms of adding to the queue but I just get a 200 response
How can I get the HttpTrigger to return an action result given that to have the messages added to a queue I need to return DispatchMessages?
Paul

I am able to send the message to Service Bus and return a Http response using below code.

using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace _78837659
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;
        private readonly IPassfortDataService _passfortDataService;
        private readonly IMyService _myService;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger, IPassfortDataService passfortDataService, IMyService myService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _myService = myService;
            _passfortDataService = passfortDataService;
        }

        [Function("Process-Duplicates")]
        public async Task<DispatchedMessages> ProcessDataAsync(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "myroute")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            // Process your data
            await _passfortDataService.ProcessDataAsync();

            HttpResponseData response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            await response.WriteStringAsync("HTTP response: Message sent");

            return new DispatchedMessages()
            {
                Messages = _myService.MessagesToBeSent.Select(x => x.ToJson()),
                HttpResponse = response
            };
        }
    }

    public class DispatchedMessages
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        [ServiceBusOutput("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
        public IEnumerable<string>? Messages { get; set; }

        public HttpResponseData HttpResponse { get; set; }

    }
}

You should have below codes in the mentioned files.
.csproj-
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RootNamespace>_78837659</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Program.cs-
using _78837659;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.AddSingleton<IPassfortDataService, PassfortDataService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

I am able to see below response while invoking the URL.



@Paul did it solve your issue?
